# file format of training/ testing dataset

Tags: dataframe

I was building lately a dataset that I gather from the internet to use for training NN models. now I have a bunch of jpg images in one file and their labels on a txt file. the question is to which file format should I convert this data to make it easily callable in frameworks (python). a second question is how to build a metadata file about this dataset and which format should it have

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easiest way is to build csv file to with two columns: directory and label. The directory value is the path (relative path) to the image, and label is of course the label. It requires you a merge from txt file and all jpg file into one csv files, but essentially it is easier to work with csv in pandas

Comment: should this relative path to the image be modified at every download of the data to others machines?

Comment: It is a bit hard to answer that question. It depends on your data and how will you use it - one time? multiple time? one user? everyone? Of course it could be one zip, contains all jpg files and csv file if you want it online

Comment: yes I want to make it online so people can use it. so if I introduce the relative path to the image in the csv file this won't be callable from other machines after download.  if I understood you well

Comment: If you use a relative path it will be callable - as long as other machines using the same directory. For example, if your csv assume all images are in same folder, what the user ("other machines") need to do is to download csv and all images to the same folder. It is a reasonable assumption